# calculating attenuation in RF data of ultrasound

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am running into something I have not yet managed to figure out after quite some googling. I should find the attenuation of an ultrasound image with different methods and then compare them; I should mention that the output should be a scaler.
In all these methods I am working with, I am stuck in the same step of all of them. How to find that number from the spectrum.
I am going to attach my code, and also the output.
My sampling frequency is 336 MHz, and the attenuation unit is dB/MHz/cm.

[image]

```
atten = imcrop(fc,[0 3900 200 2650]);
[K,L] = size(atten);
if mod(K,2) == 0 % L is even
   l = ( (-K/2) : ((K-2)/2) )/K*Fs;
 else            % L is odd
   l = ( (-(K-1)/2) : ((K-1)/2) )/K*Fs;
end
accum1 = zeros(K,1);
for i = 1:L
    FE = fftshift(abs(fft(atten(:,i))));
    power = abs(FE).^2 / K; 
    accum1 = accum1 + power;
end

figure,plot(l,log(accum1/L));
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I must admit I am not familiar with ultrasound signal processing. So it is unclear to me as a reader what exactly you are trying to achieve, and how you are approaching this problem from a programming perspective. So far you are showing us how to plot this power spectrum. So how is the attenuation you are looking for defined? Also it seems to me that this is question is not a programming problem but rather a signal processing problem. Consider asking those questions here: [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thank you so much for your comment and the link.